# How to tell if forwarded inboundcalls in Twilio were missed?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I have a twilio app: When someone calls the Twilio number and forwards it to a verified phone number. I'd like to know if that forwarded call was missed.

Is this even possible? Is it possible to do  call progress events on forwarded inbound calls via Twiml? If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 4):

I work with the devangels at Twilio.

It seems like you might be looking for the 'no-answer' Status parameter as seen here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#call-status-values

Also looks like you're using PHP so the syntax would be something like this for a loop of calls:

```
foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        "Status" => "no-answer"
        )) as $call
```

Comment: Thanks for the post it's always good to get answers from as close to the source as possible.